# How do I decrease my heading's font size in Foundation+SASS?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation through SASS, but I'm having some trouble getting to grips with how to do so properly. I have an `<h1>` that is made relatively big by Foundation's default styling. I'd like this specific heading to be a lot smaller, though.

Of course, I could write more specific CSS that applies a different font size and overrides Foundation's selector, but then I'd have to manually take into account adjusting to different screen sizes and whatever else Foundation's default styles do for you. So I was wondering whether there was a mixin or something to apply e.g. the heading styles for an `h4` heading to a certain element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just now actually came up with what is, in hindsight, a rather simply way to accomplish this. Supposing an element `<h1 class="headingToMakeSmaller">`, I simply added:

```
.headingToMakeSmaller {
      @extend h4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply go read the Foundation docs regarding **Typography** and adjusting **Header Styles** in your **_setting.scss** file.

[Here is the relevant page that answers your question >>](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/typography-base.html)

Comment: I've seen that, however, I don't want to change my header styles globally, but just for a single `<h1>` instance.